# Why Promise.resolve in Promise will execute before Promise？

Tags: javascript, promise

```js
new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(1)
}).then(a => console.log(a))
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2))
```

will print 1, 2

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2))
new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(1)
}).then(a => console.log(a))
```

will print 2, 1

but i don't understand why

```
new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(1)
    Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2))
}).then(a => console.log(a))
```

will print 2, 1

Comment: All of these are just a race between independent promise chains.  There are specs and implementations and a deep understanding of both that can predict the order, but frankly it's bad code if the order matters.  If order matters, then sequence things with promise chaining rather than creating a race between independent promise chains so you directly control when one operation happens relative to the other with your code.

Comment: in the last code snippet, the inner `.then` is added to the microtask queue before the outer one - therefore will be executed (in this case since the Promises all resolve immediately) first

Comment: Calling `resolve(1)` will not abandon the execution of the current function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promise.resolve` will return an immediately resolved promise, and calling `new Promise(resolve => { resolve() })` will also resolve right away. Just because its a promise does not make it async if you didn't do anything asynchronous with it, like throw it in a timeout, interval, etc. So:

```
// this resolves when called and logs first (1)
new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(1)
}).then(a => console.log(a))
// this resolves and logs immediately (2)
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2))
```

```
// this resolves immediately (2)
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2))
// this resolves when called (1)
new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(1)
}).then(a => console.log(a))
```

```
new Promise(resolve => {
    // this passes 1 to the then chained to this promise,
    // which won't run until this function body is done.
    resolve(1)
    // this resolves immediately and logs (2)
    Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2))
    // now we drop into then and it logs (1)
}).then(a => console.log(a))
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) for more details on `Promise.resolve`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which made me understand Promise better.

Answer (score 2):

[`Promises`](https://promisesaplus.com/) work by using the Event Loop, so any code calling promises will happen in order of resolution, regardless of order of creation.

```js
const test = Promise.resolve(1).then(console.log) // pushes chain A to loop, [A]
Promise.resolve(2).then(console.log) // pushes chain B onto loop, [A,B]
test.then(() => 3).then(console.log) // pushes chain C onto loop, [A, B, C]
//first loop resolution, 1, then console.log
//second loop resolution, 2, then console.log
//third loop resolution, 3, then console.log
```

Even though `test` was made before chain `B`, Chain `C` happens AFTER `B` because the event loop is a first in, first out model. This is because `Promise`s are `asynchronous` meaning they will resolve in the order received by the Event Loop and since resolve pushes onto the event loop without waiting on anything, it is immediately there.

```js
fetch('https://google.com').then(() => console.log(1)) // waits for networks
Promise.resolve(2).then(console.log) // pushes chain B onto loop [B]
// B resolves, 2, console.log, loop empty []
// fetch returns finally, pushes A onto loop [A]
// A resolves, 1, console.log, loop empty []
```

What you're seeing is a race condition of immediately resolving promises, meaning that they will resolve in the imperative order executed through the chains.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which made me understand Promise better.